# Javascript simple object sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, filter

I am very new to JavaScript. I was learning about array methods recently.

**What I am trying to do**

How can I turn the question object into results object by using some array methods (filter, map, etc.) or any else that can work?

**What i have already tried with working examples**

```
let question = {
  rows: [
    { no: 1, content: "a" },
    { no: 2, content: "d" },
    { no: 1, content: "b" },
    { no: 3, content: "e" },
    { no: 2, content: "c" },
    { no: 4, content: "f" },
    { no: 4, content: "g" },
  ]
};


let results = {
    rows: [
        [{ no: 1, content: "a" }, { no: 1, content: "b" }],
        [{ no: 2, content: "c" }, { no: 2, content: "d" }],
        [{ no: 3, content: "e" }],
        [{ no: 4, content: "f" }, { no: 4, content: "g" }]
    ] 
}
```

**Expected Result**

**Actual Result**

Comment: how would you solve this problem? do you have some thoughts? any tries?

Comment: Altough you are new to JS, here in StackOverflow we expect a minimun effort from the people that is asking for a solution, because we are not here to write entire solutions/free codes, we are here to help. So please, post your current code where you are trying to solve and we will be glad to help you with your function

Comment: I'm sorry guys. This is also my first time asking a question on StackOverflow.
The only thoughts I got that I only know maybe I need to use filter and map array methods.
I will update some code if I have some thoughts.

Comment: think about what you want to do, do you want to take each object in questions rows array and append it the results rows array?

Comment: you could simply swap them around

Comment: one is a one dimensional array and the other is a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can do something like this

```js
let question = {
  rows: [
    { no: 1, content: "a" },
    { no: 2, content: "d" },
    { no: 1, content: "b" },
    { no: 3, content: "e" },
    { no: 2, content: "c" },
    { no: 4, content: "f" },
    { no: 4, content: "g" }
  ]
};

// Create a result Object
let result = {};

// Do the magic
result.rows = [...new Set(question.rows.map(row => row.no))].map(key => question.rows.filter(row => row.no === key));
  
console.log(result);
```

Steps-
1. Create a unique array of `no` keys,
2. Map over keys,
3. Filter out an array of the same key (`no`) value from rows array

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and the values from it by using the key for creating the same group by reducing the array.

```js
function groupBy(array, key) {
    return Array.from(array
        .reduce((m, o) => m.set(o[key], [...(m.get(o[key]) || []), o]), new Map)
        .values()
    );
}

let question = { rows: [{ no: 1, content: "a" }, { no: 2, content: "d" }, { no: 1, content: "b" }, { no: 3, content: "e" }, { no: 2, content: "c" }, { no: 4, content: "f" }, { no: 4, content: "g" }] },
    result = { rows: groupBy(question.rows, 'no') };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called parsing, when you need to change the data structure.

You can do it without any fancy methods. Steps:

1. Create a unique array,
2. Create sub arrays if they don't already exist,
3. Add itens to their sub arrays

```js
let question = {
  rows: [
    { no: 1, content: "a" },
    { no: 2, content: "d" },
    { no: 1, content: "b" },
    { no: 3, content: "e" },
    { no: 2, content: "c" },
    { no: 4, content: "f" },
    { no: 4, content: "g" },
  ]
};

// Create a unique array
let results = {
  rows: []
};

for (let key in question.rows) {
  var item = question.rows[key];
  var no = item.no - 1;

  // Create sub arrays if they don't already exist
  if (!results.rows[no]) results.rows[no] = [];

  // Add itens to their sub arrays
  results.rows[no].push(item);
}

console.log(results);
```